# Mongo DB backup sizes

Tags: mongodb

I'm backing up a MongoDB server using (for better or worse) mongodump. After running `db.stats()` I get a `storageSize` of 8.9GB and a `dataSize` of 44.5GB. This makes sense to me as I expect a lot of the data (at least 1/2) to be highly compressible.

My question is this, why would my backup's be 45GB in size, if the storage size is only 9GB - I've also checked my actual disk usage (the disk is used ONLY for mongo and has slightly over 9GB of disk usage.

I'm running mongodump with the following options:

`/usr/bin/mongodump -h $HOST -d $DBNAME --username=$DBUSER --password=$DBPASS --archive="$OUTPUT"`

I'm aware of the gzip option, but if the data is stored compressed, surely it should be backed up compressed too - and gzip should simply be a second level of compression?

Comment: what is the MongoDB version in your environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you don't use --gzip parameter, data is at bson format what is not compressed and you can look that data with `bsondump` program. 
What mongodump do, is read data from database and that result is of course not compressed.

Here is different between those two from my system

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 61M Mar 16 06:48 data.bson
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.3M Mar 16 06:48 data.bson.gz`

Over 10 fold compression ration.

Answer (score 1):

As per `MongoDB BOL` documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/). After an unclean shutdown of a  [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) using the  [Wired Tiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/), count and size statistics reported by  [db.stats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/#db.stats) may be **`inaccurate`**.

The amount of drift depends on the number of `insert`, `update`, or `delete` operations performed between the last [checkpoint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger-checkpoints) and the unclean shutdown. Checkpoints usually occur every `60 seconds`. However, `mongod` instances running with non-default [--syncdelay](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-syncdelay) settings may have more or less frequent checkpoints.

Run [validate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/validate/#dbcmd.validate) on each collection on the `mongod` to to restore the correct statistics after an unclean shutdown.

For example the following example converts the returned values to kilobytes:

```
db.stats(1024)
```

The method **`db.stats(scale)`** returns statistics that reflect the use state of a single database. Where parameter `scale` `number` is `Optional`. The scale at which to deliver results. Unless specified, this command returns all data in bytes.

For example here I have checked for `test` database.

```
> db.stats(1024)
{
        "db" : "test",
        "collections" : 10,
        "views" : 0,
        "objects" : 46,
        "avgObjSize" : 165.89130434
        "dataSize" : 7.4521484375,
        "storageSize" : 180,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 11,
        "indexSize" : 180,
        "fsUsedSize" : 236695904,
        "fsTotalSize" : 296127484,
        "ok" : 1}
```

and also db.stats() without the `scale` parameter

```
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "test",
        "collections" : 10,
        "views" : 0,
        "objects" : 46,
        "avgObjSize" : 165.8913043478261,
        "dataSize" : 7631,
        "storageSize" : 184320,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 11,
        "indexSize" : 184320,
        "fsUsedSize" : 242376503296,
        "fsTotalSize" : 303234543616,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

here you can see the some subtle difference size of both command.

**Note:** The scale factor rounds values to whole numbers.

The  [**`db.stats()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/) method is a wrapper around the  [**`dbStats`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbcmd.dbStats) database command.

The command takes the following syntax:

```
db.runCommand({ dbStats: 1, scale: 1 })
```

where scale is optional and defaults to `1`.

**`dbStats.dataSize`**

The total size of the uncompressed data held in this database. The `dataSize` decreases when you remove `documents`.

For databases using the  [`MMAPv1`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/mmapv1/) storage engine, dataSize includes preallocated space and the  [padding factor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-padding-factor). The dataSize does not decrease when documents shrink.

For databases using the [`WiredTiger`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger-compression) storage engine, dataSize may be larger than storageSize if compression is enabled. The dataSize decreases when documents shrink.

**`dbStats.storageSize`**

The total amount of space allocated to collections in this database for  [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document) storage. The [storageSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbStats.storageSize) does not decrease as you remove or shrink documents. This value may be smaller than dataSize for databases using the WiredTiger storage engine with [compression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger-compression) enabled.

For your further ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253397/how-to-run-mongodump-command-in-spawn-exec-child-process-with-arguments?rq=1), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439068/tar-gzip-mongo-dump-like-mysql)